# How to find anything in a level-structured table?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have trouble making query to a level-structured table:

```
select *
from user_info
where user = 1;

user level value
1    1     Jackson
1    2     Pollock
1    3     1989-02-03
1    4     male
1    5     single
```

What if I want to get all users that have exactly same values in levels 1, 2, 3 and 4 that user 1 has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest method is `listagg()`:

```
with u as (
      select u.user, listagg(value, '|') within group (order by level) as vals
      from user_info u
      where level between 1 and 4
     )
select
from u join
     u1
     on u.vals = u1.vals and u1.user = 1;
```

The more traditional method is a self-join:

```
select u.user
from user_info u join
     user_info u1
     on u1.level = u.level and
        u1.value = u.value and
        u1.user = 1
where u1.level between 1 and 4
group by u.user
having count(*) = 4;   -- four levels match
```